# How to deal with autocorrelation with earth (MARSpline estimation)

Tags: r, autocorrelation, splines, mars

What do you consider to be the best way to proceed to estimate a time series in a MARSpline estimation (using R package `earth`)?

Would it be correct to run:

1. Estimate `earth`
2. Extract the enhanced X matrix for an `auto.arima` with `xreg` detection?

Comment: Best work on this subject can be found in this article https://www.jstor.org/stable/2290499?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents no software implementation yet.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but I meant, after running MARS estimation, if we have an autocorrelation function for the fitted residuals revealing teh existence of MA terms, what do you consider to  the best way to proceed. In the L&S paper they did not deal with this.

Comment: I would recommend lagging the dependent variable.